# How to set keyword in jquery selector as variable?

Tags: jquery

What I am doing is scanning a page for a link that contains the given keywords, and if it finds the link, it navigates to it. If not, it refreshes the page. I would like to set the keywords as an array. This is my code:

```
var keywords = ["kw1", "kw2"];
var link = $("a[href*=keyword[0]][href*=keyword[1]]").attr('href');
if (link) {
   window.location.href = link;
} else {
   window.location.reload();
}
```

I am getting this error in the google chrome console

Error: Syntax error, unrecognized expression: a[href*=keyword[0]][href*=keyword[1]]

What am I doing wrong? How can I fix this? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

its a string, and to add a variable to string you concat it :

```
var string_var = "bla"
var string_example = "blablabla" + string_var ;
```

therefore:

```
var keywords = ["kw1", "kw2"];
var link = $("a[href*='"+keywords[0]+"'][href*='"+keywords[1]+"']").attr('href');
if (link) {
   window.location.href = link;
} else {
   window.location.reload();
}
```